# Issues with simple task: Conditional statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm doing a school task with conditional statements. I'm trying to code something that asks for the amount of pets the user has and then combine the answers, which will return a value/answer depending on the earlier given values.

```
const dogs = prompt('How many dogs do you have?');
dogs = parseInt(dogs);

const cats = prompt('How many cats do you have?');
cats = parseInt(cats);

const otherPets = prompt('How many other pets do you have?');
otherPets = parseInt(otherPets);

const totalPets = 'dogs' + 'cats' + 'otherPets';

if (totalPets > 0){

alert('You have a total of 'totalPets'pets.');
}

else{

alert('You should probably get yourself a sloth.');
}
```

Comment: **const totalPets = dogs + cats + otherPets;** try this.

Comment: It still doesn't work:( I get this on Chrome Console; Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) will not allow you to re-declare the variable. For that use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
And for the `totalPets`, you don't need to add `'` around the variables you declared above. That statement will simply join all the strings together.

Your code can be rewritten like this:

```js
let dogs = prompt('How many dogs do you have?');
dogs = parseInt(dogs);

let cats = prompt('How many cats do you have?');
cats = parseInt(cats);

let otherPets = prompt('How many other pets do you have?');
otherPets = parseInt(otherPets);

const totalPets = dogs + cats + otherPets;

if (totalPets > 0) {
    alert(`You have a total of ${totalPets} pets.`);
} else {
    alert('You should probably get yourself a sloth.');
}
```

And to use variables in a string you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

There were synatx mistakes in your code, I have fixed it. Please see below:

```js
let dogs = prompt('How many dogs do you have?');
dogs = parseInt(dogs);

let cats = prompt('How many cats do you have?');
cats = parseInt(cats);

let otherPets = prompt('How many other pets do you have?');
otherPets = parseInt(otherPets);

const totalPets = dogs + cats + otherPets;

if (totalPets > 0) {

  alert('You have a total of ' + totalPets + ' pets.');
} else {

  alert('You should probably get yourself a sloth.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```js
if (totalPets > 0) {
    alert('You have a total of 'totalPets'pets.');
}
```

to

```js
if (totalPets > 0) {
    alert('You have a total of ' + totalPets + ' pets.');
}
```

In JavaScript, the `+` operator is used for concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

For details on string concatentation, [check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
const dogs = prompt('How many dogs do you have?'); dogs = parseInt(dogs);

const cats = prompt('How many cats do you have?'); cats = parseInt(cats);

const otherPets = prompt('How many other pets do you have?'); otherPets = parseInt(otherPets);

const totalPets = dogs + cats + otherPets;

if (totalPets > 0) {
 // whenever you're mixing string with numbers, you need string concatenation
 // to convert your number into string 
 alert(`You have a total of pets. ${totalPets}`); 
} else{
 alert('You should probably get yourself a sloth.'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

const dogs = parseInt(prompt('How many dogs do you have?'))

const cats = parseInt(prompt('How many cats do you have?'))

const otherPets = parseInt(prompt('How many other pets do you have?'))

const totalPets = dogs + cats + otherPets;

if (totalPets > 0){

alert(`You have a total of ${totalPets} pets`)
}

else{

alert('You should probably get yourself a sloth.') }
    </script>
```